# not able to upload larger files in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

not able to upload , larger files . 
My code is working good as it works well for files less than 2MB but for more than 2 MB it fails . 
being a shared hosting I can even track the error log . 
any standard method , kindly suggest .

Comment: See your php.ini for upload max file size. It is set to 2 MB  by default

Comment: Have a look at this existing post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: it was the problem of the php.ini file only, although I was trying to include some custom php.ini file the system was taking this as the primary and was getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload max file size has to be updated, as correctly pointed by @saba-tandashvili.
After updating the PHP.ini file, I restarted the HTTPD Services. and it worked as per expectations.